# Semantically store RGB colour values

Tags: javascript

Would it be more semantic to store them as an array:

```js
var niceBlue = [27, 125, 161];
```

or an object:

```js
var coolGreen = {red: 74, green: 173, blue: 90};
```

or as an object with shorthand property names: (and then, would it be better to uppercase the property names or not?)

```js
var deepPurple = {r: 86, g: 45, b: 92};
```

Comment: It depends, what do you do with them? For example, if you only intend to use them without modification in css, you might as well store them as an hex string.

Comment: What do you mean by 'more semantic'? More readable to another user? If you want to be really clear what you are doing, another option might be to create a Color class with .red, .green, .blue properties, with .getHex() or getRGB() methods...depending on how many you are going to be handling in your code.

Comment: I want to store them as RGB because they will be manipulated by JS, I just want to set a standard to follow with them.

Comment: @Toby I feel a Colour class would be overkill, I don't need to convert them between hex/RGB, I'm after a solution that's readable and logical but not too verbose.

Comment: For readability, I would go for an object instead of an array with full lowercase names.

Comment: @darklinen - in that case, I'd say just go for {red:255,green:255; blue:255}. My reasoning being that the full property name is much more readable that way. Although I don't agree that a Color class is overkill. I think it's always better to avoid anonymous json objects. They soon become a code smell. Say you decide to add an alpha property at a later date. Now you have to pick through all your code to add {alpha:100} instead of just setting a default value in your Color class... I will add an answer to show what I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: using a Color class being overkill... this is just a few lines of code, but it gives you a much more scalable solution

```
function Color(red,green,blue)
{
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
}

var red = new Color(255,0,0)
var green = new Color(0,255,0)
var blue = new Color(0,0,255);
```

Going forward, if you decide to add an alpha property, no problem.

```
function Color(red,green,blue,alpha)
{
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
    this.alpha = (alpha!=undefined)? alpha: 100;

}

var red = new Color(255,0,0)
var green = new Color(0,255,0)
var blue = new Color(0,0,255);
var alpha = new Color(255,0,0,50)
```

All your original objects will still work fine. And you can easily add a toNumber(), or a toString() method for debugging purposes. It doesn't seem like overkill to me. I'd always advise against using anonymous JSON wrappers as data transfer objects. They soon come back and bite you. :)

Bottom line - if you are taking the trouble to think about semantics and readability, then your code sounds like it is ready for some 'classes'.

Comment: You got your case for alpha back-to-front.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used 'classes' and taken the OO approach so I'm a bit hesitant there, but you're right, this is a nice solution. Where's the best place to put the class? I have a namespace for my code and an init inside it like `var myApp = {userOptions: {...}, init: function() {...}}`. Most of my code's inside the init, is it a good idea to put it there?

Comment: @darklinen - you would add this function anywhere within the relevant scope to allow you to use it. Personally, I would declare this function as a global one, so any of your code anywhere can instantiate a new Color(). But if you have your code separated into namespaces, then you could declare it whereever makes most sense. I actually use a namespace framework which would let me create something like core.utils.Color or something like this...but this is just a glorified global variable in real terms.